# how to close window from another class in java swing?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

### Heading ## 1. List item

i wrote code as desiging part in one class by extending JFrame class, and action listeners for buttons in another class(not inner class) and finally for main method i taken separate class. here in listener class i am closing present window and opening new window. i am able open new window. but i cant close existing window. please help me.(i am not able to access setVisible() method)
thanks 
hari.
here my code is

```
CredentialsForm .java

public CredentialsForm()
    {

        btnGetSessionKey.addActionListener(new ButSesKeyListener());
        btnGoToMessaging.addActionListener(new ButGoToMesListener());
        btnGoToMessaging.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));    


        btnGetSessionKey.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        lblAutomationId.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblYouSessionKey.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));        
        lblEncryptionKey.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblSingleSignOn.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblUserName.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        lblEmail.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));        
        tfGoToMessaging.setColumns(10);
        tfGetSessionKey.setColumns(10);
        tfEncryptionKey.setColumns(10);
        tfSingleSignOn.setColumns(10);
        tfUserName.setColumns(10);
        tfEmail.setColumns(10);
        tfAutomationId.setColumns(10);

        initGUI();
    }
```

Comment: please provide the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

> i am not able to access setVisible() method

In your ActionListener you can write generic code to access the current window:

```
Component button = (Component)event.getSource();
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button);
window.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class FirstFrame extends JFrame {
 // your all coding..
}

public class SecondFrame extends JFrame {
   public static FirstFrame first;

   public static void main(String[] a){
       // show the first...

       // anywhere you hide first using first.setVisible(false);
   }
}
```